# Can we install Business Central Workbench 7.36 on TomcatServer?

Tags: drools

Can we install the business central workbench  7.36 on the tomcat server. In the documentation , only the wars related to the wildfly server are present.

https://www.drools.org/download/download.html

Business Central Workbench

Business Central Workbench is the web application and repository to govern Drools and jBPM assets. See documentation for details about installation.

WildFly 14 WAR

Can you point me to the tomcat installation version of it

Comment: Only the Wildfly WARs are built anymore, though the documentation still references Tomcat distributions. You could always download it and try it out, but the docs (which admittedly are not too accurate here) indicate the Wildfly WAR is built using the Wildfly native containers. Looks like 7.11 was the last release with a Tomcat war (it was called "drools workbench" back then.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer to this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.33.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_tomcat_7_x8_x) for installing Business central or jBPM on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It only refers to the wildfly or jboss eap servers. It doesnt show the war file for installing it on tomcat server.

11. Business Central (General)
    11.1. Installation
    11.1.1. War installation
    Use the war from the Business Central distribution zip that corresponds to your application server. The differences between these war files are mainly superficial. For example, some JARs might be excluded if the application server already supplies them.

eap7: tailored for Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7

wildfly14: tailored for Wildfly 14